# Convert Int em bool

Tags: c#, controller

Pessoal preciso de uma ajuda de vocês [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
    if (usr.Excluido = 0)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Usuário bloqueado.");
        return View(model);
    }
```

A variavel excluido está como bool em meu sistema, estou fazendo uma verificação de login, caso **Excluido = 0** o usuario tem acesso ao sistema caso seja **Excluido = 1** ele cai dentro deste if

```
if (usr.Excluido = 0)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Usuário bloqueado.");
                return View(model);
            }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Não é possível comparar inteiros com booleanos.

**Um adendo importante:** Se em seu banco você vê 1 ou 0, estou supondo que esteja usando SQL Server, e, booleanos no SQL Server é configurado como Bit (true ou false; 1 ou 0) - E isso não necessariamente é um inteiro.

Na imagem que postou é claro o entendimento.

Então, seu caso a comparação deve ser feita da seguinte maneira:

```
if (usr.Excluido == true)
{
    //Sua implementação aqui...
}
```

Ou...

```
if (usr.Excluido)
{
    //Sua implementação aqui...
}
```

Mas pelo que entendi, é que deseja comparar `usr.Excluido` é um objeto boolano e `usuarioLogado.Excluido` é a flag que vem do seu banco, mas é do tipo inteiro.

Se for isso mesmo que eu entendi, então ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
if (usr.Excluido == Convert.ToBoolean(usuarioLogado.Excluido))
{
    //Sua implementação aqui...
}
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

Então a comparação deve ser feita com dois iguais (==), então seu codigo ficará assim:

```
if (usr.Excluido == 0)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Usuário bloqueado.");
    return View(model);
}
```

Exemplo: http://rextester.com/RLBL96990

Comment: Eu ja tinha feito isso e da o mesmo erro

Comment: postei uma outra foto no topico

Comment: Deveria funcionar conforme exemplo: http://rextester.com/RLBL96990

Comment: Sim, só que a minha variavel esta como bool ou é true ou é false, só que não estou conseguindo fazer a validação com true ou false

Comment: Então é so usar um true false, não precisa da comparação numerica

Comment: O @breno respondeu a forma correta para sua realiza

Comment: Então o problema é que com true ou false não estou esta entrando no if que seria ModelState.AddModelError("", "Usuário bloqueado.");

Comment: Não faz sentido, teria que entrar

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66886/discussion-between-luiz-santos-and-leonardo-macedo).

Answer (score 0):

Em C#, você não pode comparar inteiros com booleanos. Sua propriedade é booleana, então você deve compara-la apenas com os valores `true` ou `false`.

No seu caso, a comparação deve ser feita da seguinte maneira:

```
if (usr.Excluido == true)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Usuário bloqueado.");
    return View(model);
}
```

Se quiser, também pode omitir a comparação, levando em consideração o valor da própria propriedade para execução do `if`:

```
if (usr.Excluido)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Usuário bloqueado.");
    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Então @BrunoCosta eu fiz o teste tipo, eu tenho dois usuarios no meu banco um com excluido = 0 e um excluido = 1 
Se eu tento fazer o login com os dois usuarios não cai dentro do if o que esta bloqueado

Comment: então faça uma comparação do `usr.Excluido` com a propriedade vinda do seu banco, como por exemplo: `if (usr.Excluido && usuarioBanco.Excluido == 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Não vejo o porque comparar bool com int.
A maneira correta de fazer o que você está querendo (pelo que entendi) seria:

```
if (usr.Excluido)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Usuário bloqueado.");
    return View(model);
}
```

Não tem porque o código acima dar errado. 
Mas caso queira mesmo converter int em bool você pode usar o seguinte código:

```
bool fromInt(int i)
{
    if (i == 0)
        return false;
    return true;
}
...
if (usr.Excluido == fromInt(1))
{
   ModelState.AddModelError("", "Usuário bloqueado.");
   return View(model);
}
```

Obs: Você deve usar dois iguais `==` para comparação, e não somente um (`=`).